# How to properly implement the top back button in navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, back-button

I'm currently trying to add a navigation drawer to my weather app, so I watched a youtube
tutorial on it and was able to implement it the way I wanted to until I realized
that the tutorial I watched didn't cover how I can implement the up/top back
button for the nav drawer so as a matter of fact, I currently cannot get back to
my default fragment after opening any of the nav tabs. I searched several
sites and youtube videos looking for tutorials on how to implement the top back
button but haven't seen/been able to find it. I also searched this site and still
haven't found anyone with a similar issue here. Please, can anyone be of help?

Here's a screenshot of how my app currently is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeSjV.png but if I open any of the navbar options i.e settings and click back, I can't return back to the default fragment where the weather is displayed. It also doesn't have an up-back button as well.

Currently, clicking back only exits the app.

This is the only code I've tried and it didn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();//check currently how many frags loaded
        if (backStackCount > 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(); //go back to previously loaded fragment
        }   
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It gave the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol
> int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();//check currently how many
> frags loaded

Here's my activity code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    // Last update time, click sound, search button, search panel.
    TextView timeField;
    MediaPlayer player;
    ImageView Search;
    EditText textfield;
    // For scheduling background image change(using constraint layout, start counting from dubai, down to statue of liberty.
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count = 0;
    int[] drawable = new int[]{R.drawable.dubai, R.drawable.norway, R.drawable.eiffel_tower, R.drawable.hong_kong, R.drawable.statue_of_liberty,
            R.drawable.beijing, R.drawable.chicago, R.drawable.colombia, R.drawable.vienna,R.drawable.tokyo};
    Timer _t;

    private WeatherDataViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        // use home activity layout.

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Allow activity to make use of the toolbar

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WeatherDataViewModel.class);

        // Trigger action to open & close nevigation drawer
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar
                , R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        timeField = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        Search = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        textfield = findViewById(R.id.textfield);
        //  find the id's of specific variables.

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        // host 3 fragments along with bottom navigation.
        final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        assert navHostFragment != null;
        final NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        // Make hourly & daily tab unusable
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
            return false;
        });

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> navController.popBackStack(destination.getId(), false));

        // For scheduling background image change
        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
        _t = new Timer();
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run on ui thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (count < drawable.length) {

                        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                        count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);

        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // make click sound when search button is clicked.
                player = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this, R.raw.click);
                player.start();

                getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                // make use of some fragment's data

                Fragment currentFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                if (currentFragment instanceof FirstFragment) {
                    FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) currentFragment;
                    firstFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                } else if (currentFragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
                    SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) currentFragment;
                    secondFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                } else if (currentFragment instanceof ThirdFragment) {
                    ThirdFragment thirdFragment = (ThirdFragment) currentFragment;
                    thirdFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                }
            }

            private void getWeatherData(String name) {

                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Example> call, @NonNull Response<Example> response) {

                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            timeField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            timeField.setText("First Updated:" + " " + response.body().getDt());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            timeField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            timeField.setText("First Updated: Unknown");
                            Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Settings()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.ads_upgrade_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Upgrade()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.privacy_policy_id:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
                        new Privacy_Policy()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            // Open/close drawer animation
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please if there's anything I should correct/add, let me know

Comment: Hey Richard.. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026718/navigation-component-how-to-show-a-normal-up-back-button-instead-of-hamburger-i/68038101#68038101) could help you out

Comment: @zain The preview you shared is quite different from how I would love my app to
be done. When you clicked the navbar on your app, it displayed home as the 
first bar on that side meaning that the entire app is being controlled by the
navbar, it has no other default fragment normally controlled before adding
additional items to the app using the navbar. Also, your codes were written in
Kotlin.

Comment: @zain I don't want my app to be controlled using the navbar, I designed the navbar
just for additional things like settings, upgrade to remove ads, and privacy 
policy(like how AccuWeather nav bar is). I've posted a screenshot of it for easy
Identification. Any suggestion on how I can go about it or do you know of any
way to do it? If not, I'll have to bounty the code, thanks for your previous
suggestion.

Comment: I've adjusted that on java; pls check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();//check currently how many frags loaded
    if (backStackCount > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(); //go back to previously loaded fragment
    }   
}
```

> Currently, clicking back only exits the app.

Using `popBackStack()` will pop up the backstack making your app exists, but you just need to return to the default fragment.

To fix this, you need to change the behavior of the drawer burger button, so that it can be used sometimes to open the drawer navView layout, and other times to back to the default fragment; the later is when you want to add the top back button instead.

> how I can implement the up/top back button for the nav drawer

This requires to access the [`setToolbarNavigationClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle#setToolbarNavigationClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) method which enables you add a listener to burger clicks.

In this case you need to return back to the home fragment as you need, in the `onCreate()` method add:

```
toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Enable the functionality of opening the side drawer, when the burger icon is clicked
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true); // Show the burger icon & enable the drawer funcionality
        navController.navigate(R.id.home); // Back to default fragment (replace home with your default fragment id in the navGraph)
    }
});
```

The remaining part is to show the back button whenever you want to go to certain fragment

And use `toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` to enable/disable the functionality of opening/closing the drawer when the home/burger icon is clicked

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {

        // Repeat this condition for all the Fragments that you want to show the back button
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.settings_id) { // replace `settings_id` with your fragment id in the navGraph that you want to show the back button
            // Disable the functionality of opening the side drawer, when the burger icon is clicked & show the UP button instead
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

        } 

    }
});
```

Comment: Good day zain, please can you look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70776783/16020235 I've gotten an answer for it that works but it interferes with my sound, I believe you'll be able to handle it since you have the sound information

Answer (score 1):

You can try add `app:startDestination="@+id/your default fragment"` attribute in your mobile_navigation.xml's root layout.

mobile_navigation.xml is a file where you manage your fragments like in this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home"> 

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.example.navd.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
    android:name="com.example.navd.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
    android:name="com.example.navd.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />
```

Comment: I already have that added

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override the `onKeyDown` at the `MainActivity`, which controlls the behavior of the virtual back button of the entire app. Right now any click on this button exits the app because you have only one "page" that holds the `fragments` and switches between them, so if you go back from this single page, you exit the app...

I have a `public String` at the `MainActivty` that holds the current_fragment and I update it each time I switch `fragment`:

**MainActivity** (before `onCreate()`)

```
public String current_page = "";
```

**any Fragment**

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mainActivity.current_fragment = "anyFragment";
```

**home Fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mainActivity.current_fragment = "home_page";
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) { // you only want to treat the back click, not any click...

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) { // if drawer is open, close it

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        } else if (!current_page.equals ("home_page") {

            setHomePage(); // a method that switch the fragment to homePageFragment
            return true;

        } 
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

About setHomePage () - that is a method for switching between Fragments, like you do at your app already...

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion, I'm currently working on it.

I'm using this code after my onBackPressed(). I hope that's the right place to 
use it?
Secondly, the drawerLayout part showed an error so I replaced it with drawer(the official name, not the id) and it
stopped. Finally, please what do the "current_page" and "setHomePage" parts
represent? because I'm getting errors on both parts.

Comment: @Richard Wilson First, don't use `onBackPresed()` at all. Use this method below, `onKeyDown`, at `MainActivity`. Secondly, yes, of course you need to use your DrawerLayout variable name. Finally, I edited and extend my explanation about **current_page** and **setHomePage**. See below

Comment: Now I'm really confused about where to write the "any Fragment and 
"home Fragment" code. I wrote the "any Fragment" codes on both my privacy
policy and upgrade to remove ads fragments and they both bring the error: cannot resolve conflict "current_fragment" while I wrote the "home Fragment" code on the 
Settings fragment(which is the first tab on the navbar) and it brings the error
cannot resolve conflict "home Fragment". Then HomeActivity gives the error:
cannot resolve method "setHomePage".

Comment: I read and practiced java for 6 months using head first java. Then 3 months on practical android before I started this as my first project. So you can't expect me to be an expert as just my first

Comment: but regardless, I've later figured out that the problem with this is a different thing which I wrote in my new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70544289/16020235

Comment: I could have deleted this one but StackOverflow warned against it.